# Can I be demoted In HotS ranked 1v1?

Tags: starcraft-2, battle.net

During the current season (2014 Season 2), is it possible for me to be demoted after my placement matches? If I consistently play below the average skill of my current league is it possible I will get demoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blizzard removed in-season demotions as a way of encouraging people to play more games without fear of demotion (allegedly to increase competition within leagues).

That being said, the league you're in is just a rough indication of your skill level and MMR (Match making rating).  If you're in gold, there's nothing stopping you from playing players in bronze league, if your MMR drops that low.

If you really want to demote yourself, you can do so by pressing the "Leave League" button on the ladder page, or waiting until next season.

Info here:

http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/blog/10117387/starcraft-ii-ladder-league-and-season-faq-5-31-2013

Comment: Well that's just hilarious.

Comment: Holy drastic changes... Oh wait. What? That article is from 2013 but it's not true. You could drop leagues. I'm not convinced you can't do it now. Something is wrong here. Also Leave League doesn't demote you. It doesn't change your "skill rating" at all. It just removes you from your league.

Comment: Right, so if you feel you should be demoted, you leave your league and then play another placement match and you can be demoted.  This assumes your MMR is below your current league